# php eval condition understanding

Tags: php

I am learning PHP. I see a code including "eval" below:

```
<?php
$name = 'cup';
$string = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
echo $str. "\n";

eval("\$cup = \"$str\";");           
echo $cup. "\n";
?>
```

My question is about `"\$cup = \"$str\";"` . Why do I have to use `\`, `"` and `;` to run the above code? Simply `eval($cup = $str)` gives me error.

Comment: _“I am learning PHP.”_ – then you best forget that `eval` exists right now. Whenever you might be tempted to use it, look real hard if there is not a better way of achieving what is needed.

Comment: If Eval is your answer, your almost definitely asking the wrong questions.

Comment: I already have gotten my answer from Simone Nigro and it is clear to me now. Also, eval is not my answer. I was confused about parameter inside eval. Now I have known that it only holds PHP statements in the form of string. And it was my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `eval($cup = $str)` is wrog, [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) need a string, eg;

```
eval('$cup = $str;'); // this work
```

now, if use double quote, eg

```
eval("\$cup = \"$str\";");
```

in double quote strings variables in the strings will be evaluated. eg:

```
$cup = 'hello';
$str = 'world';
eval("$cup = \"$str\";"); // eval("hello = \"world\";");
```

`\`is a escape characters

```
$cup = 'hello';
$str = 'world';
eval("\$cup = \"$str\";"); // eval("$cup = \"world\";");
```

recommended reading: [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Side note: [PHP eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php) (use very, very careful)